# HtmlUnit 2.17 have issues with Java 7

Tags: java, web-crawler, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

My This code works with Java6 but not with Java7.
I used both HtmlUnit2.12 and HtmlUnit2.17, nothing works. Please suggest what I am missing here?

From Java7 I am getting this Exception : java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        String url = "http : / / kellyserviceshk . force . com / careers";
        String content = fetchPage(url, "firefox", 30000, true);
        System.out.println(content);
    }

    private static String fetchPage(String url, String browser, long delayinmillis, boolean javaScriptEnable) {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(javaScriptEnable);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

        String content="";
        try {               
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(delayinmillis);
            content = page.asXml();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(webClient!=null){
                webClient.closeAllWindows();
                webClient=null;
            }

        }
        return content;
    }

}
```

While changing HtmlUnit2.17 I Used BrowserVersion as FIREFOX_38, not FIREFOX_17.
What changes should I make?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to define the timeout:

```
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(0); // zero for an infinite wait. (time in milliseconds)
```

The default timeout is 90 seconds (it was 0 up to HtmlUnit-2.11).

Comment: Just an observation: Depending on your circumstances, changing this option cold be dangerous. I had same problem as OP. After I `.setTimeout(0)`, the runtime for one of my tests went from minutes to hours!